# input type "range" is ignored by html2canvas and jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

input type "range" is ignored by html2canvas and jspdf.
all other elements are perfectly rendered into the PDF.

Below is the JS snippet:

```
    document.getElementById("download")
.addEventListener("click", () => {


  HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(origFn) {
    return function(type, attribs) {
      attribs = attribs || {};
      attribs.preserveDrawingBuffer = true;
      return origFn.call(this, type, attribs);
    };
  }(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext);
    

    const mapDownload = this.document.getElementById("mapDownload");
    console.log(window);
    var opt = {
        margin: 1,
        filename: 'myfile.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: { scale: 2, useCORS: true, },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'landscape' }
    };
    html2pdf().from(mapDownload).set(opt).save();
})
```

Is there anything that i am missing out here?

Web page with range input:
[image]

PDF downloaded with missing range input
[image]

Comment: Yeah pretty sure this can't really be rendered as is, as it's technically an empty element with some user agent shadow content that it probably can't read. It also looks different per OS, so how would this work? (also Hi again! I recognise that map)

Comment: Hi again and thank you for the suggestion @somethinghere. Do we have an alternative to make this work ?

Comment: Not really... You will have to make some visual representation that _can_ be included... Not sure what the best solution is here.